# Can I ask conversational questions? (Training)

Tags: discussion

I would like to ask the following question but is DBA Stackexchange the right place? Is there any place on Stackexchange for it?

Please do answer the questions above, if you would, not the question below. I'm not trying to circumvent anything.

I'm a DBA currently working with SQL2008R2 for the most part. I've sat certified courses SQL2008R2 but sat no exams.

I've received a free course and can choose from one of

**Course M10775 - 5 days
Administering Microsoft SQL Server 2012 Databases
(Exam 70-462)**

OR

**Course M10777 - 5 days
Implementing a Data Warehouse with Microsoft SQL Server 2012
(Exam 70-463)**

The former may be good as an upgrade course but I'm not clear I'd learn any new fundementals. As it stands I have zero exposure to SQL2012.

Data Warehousing sounds like it may be more interesting. I've built DataMarts before and administered a Data Warehouse but I'm not really clear how well those could be said to be.

I'm expecting to be without employment in the next 6months and having a few certs to my name may be useful.

Comment: [The Heap](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/179/the-heap-consultancy-)

Comment: How did you get a free course?

Comment: When I filled in the survey at the end of a previous course I commented the poor air quality was disgraceful and made it hard to concentrate and stay awake in the afternoon. They offered a free course of my choice in a follow up. May be because it was corporate.

Comment: I reckon that the question, as proposed by jcolebrand below, is valid and useful -- especially for SQL Server database admins in general. If you ask that question in the regular DB admin SE, I'd answer it. Also, I would personally search the site first to see if something like it has already been asked.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think maybe with the focus:

> How do I determine which of these exams is most likely to benefit me in the future?

The goal being to make the question about the decision process, and not so much about the decision itself.

Otherwise, I think you're fine to ask that sort of thing on the site.

Comment: That's a good way to think on it. Thankyou.